# lemonbar in openbox always ontop of other applications

Tags: arch-linux, openbox, dock

[lemonbar](https://github.com/LemonBoy/bar) seems to stay ontop of every other application I run, even fullscreen applications like games and videos. I use a wrapper called [captain](https://github.com/muse/Captain), but I can play with the starting parameters of lemonbar if that helps. I also tried to tinker the openbox settings for docking applications but that did not influence the bahaviour of lemonbar it seems.